c++ or Mathematica for large eigenvalue problem
I need to find eigenvalues of very large matrices ($10^7\times 10^7$). To be precise: I only need the lowest eigenvalues (lets say the 100 lowest). Most of the matrix elements are zero ($\approx 99,999\%$). I am asking myself if it is useful to write a code in C++ (for example the Arnoldi method) or if it is possible to calculate the eigenvalues directly with Mathematica. Would a (well written) code in C++ be faster or more accurate?
Thanks for answers

From this Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors use ARPACK Arnoldi methods.  so I doubt your C++ code will be better than ARPACK unless you call ARPACK from C++ also !  From the net ARPACK  is a Fortran package which provides routines for quickly finding a few eigenvalues/eigenvectors of large sparse matrices.

Mathematica's Eigensystem takes a special code branch when you call it on a self-adjoint, sparse matrix A. You should get the $k$-lowest eigenvalues and eigenvectors by calling Eigensystem[A,k]. (If you do not need the eigenvectors, then call Eigenvalues[A,k]. You may stress that Arnoldi's method is used by issuing the option Method->"Arnoldi" (but it is the default for sparse arrays, IIRC).
You should also have a look at Method->"FEAST"; it can extract also single eigenvalues in the middle of the spectrum (see the "Options" section in the documentation of Eigensystem.
Of course, the Mathematica implementations are not always "bleeding edge". It is not unlikely that you find some newer, more performant algorithm out there (or one that is more adapted to your actual problem). And in this case this algorithm is quite likely implemented in C or C++. Then LibraryLink would allow you to write a Mathematica interface to it. But that should really be your last resort. Do it only if you are not satisfied with the performance or accuracy of Eigensystem with Method->"Arnoldi".

Thanks for the answer. Will Eigensystem also work fine if my matrix is not self adjoint?

I am not sure. The documentation is about arbitrary sparse matrices and also mentions complex eigenvalues. So I think, yes, it is supposed to work. Alas, I think I recall that some users here occasionally experienced some strange behavior with non-selfadjoint matrices. (I cannot really remember whether that was a real issue or just some fault on the user's side.) So, better check the results of Eigenvalues for correctness (which is something you should do anyways).

Ok. Thanks a lot for fast help :)

You're welcome.

If you use the CompileFunction in the Mathematica, the code will be compiled to a C program which is likely to be even faster than the C++ program.

No, it won't. Eigenvalues is not compilable, probably because its backend is already compiled. (Btw., the downvote is not from me.)
